# Write BOM to stream in Swift

Tags: swift, csv, swift4

How can I write BOM to a swift stream? I need it to export a file to excel.

What I did, but didn't work (wrong data written in output):

```
let BOM = "\u{FEFF}"
var path = docPath + "/list.csv"

let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: path, append: false)

stream?.open()
var i1:UInt8=254
var i2:UInt8=255
stream?.write(&i1, maxLength: 1)
stream?.write(&i2, maxLength: 1)
```

Comment: `but didn't work` - this is kinda vague, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Assuming you want to create a CSV file **in UTF-8** for MS-Excel.

```
var path = docPath + "/list.csv"

if let stream = OutputStream(toFileAtPath: path, append: false) {
    stream.open()
    let BOM = "\u{FEFF}"
    stream.write(BOM, maxLength: 3) //BOM in UTF-8 is made of 3 bytes.
    //...
} else {
    print("Failed to create OutputStream:", path)
}
```

With directly passing Swift String to `write(_:maxLength:)` (where the type of the first parameter is `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`), Swift generates a temporary UTF-8 representation of the String, so it may work if you want to create a file in UTF-8.

When you use this code, you need to output all items in UTF-8 and some items need escaping. I hope you know all about such things.

This code works well with Japanese-localized MS-Excel, but I'm not sure if it may work in other localizations.